# How to check whether i submit blank input in javascript? i have written a program but it is not working

Tags: javascript, submit

I have written a javascript code in an HTML file using a script tag,
where I want to know whether my input is greater than or less than 10
or equals to 10 or any blank input. I use the if-else method to solve
this problem, but my last else if condition which is "Your input is
blank" not outputting in any way.

```js
//f1 function will run when some hit the submit button
function f1() {
  //here we are taking the value of the input field using id "myinput" in the variable called myinputvar
  var myinputvar = document.getElementById("myinput").value;
  if (myinputvar > 10) {
    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "Your input number is greater than 10";
  } else if (myinputvar < 10) {
    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "Your input number is less than 10";
  } else if (myinputvar = 10) {
    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "Your input number is 10";
  } else if (myinputvar = " ") {
    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "Your input is blank";
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- this is the input tag to take inputs from user -->
Enter a integer number between 0 to anynumber = <input type="text" id="myinput"><br><br>
<!-- this is the button to submit the value -->
<button onclick="f1()">submit</button>
<!-- this is the heading tag to print the output -->
<h1 id="txt"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap in a form and make it required

Also cast to number

```js
document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop submission
  //here we are taking the value of the input field using id "myinput" in the variable called myinputvar
  var myinputvar = +document.getElementById("myinput").value; // make it a number
  if (myinputvar > 10) {
    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "Your input number is greater than 10";
  } else if (myinputvar < 10) {
    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "Your input number is less than 10";
  } else if (myinputvar = 10) {
    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "Your input number is 10";
  } else if (myinputvar = " ") {
    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "Your input is blank";
  }
})
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  Enter a integer number between 0 to anynumber =
  <input type="text" required id="myinput"><br><br>
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
<h1 id="txt"></h1>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a tricky way for me, but it works also. I wanted to avoid the inbuilt functions of javascript and make it very simple. thank you for responding.

Comment: Required is not js at all

Answer (score 0):

A general way to check for only whitespace input uses the regex pattern `^\s*$`.  Sample code:

```
if (/^\s*$/.test(inputvar)) {
    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "Your input is blank";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. it actually worked but in a nested if-else.

Answer (score 0):

pay attention not to use the shortcut:

```
if (inputvar) {
    // this won't catch "0"!
}
```

but the more proper

```
if (inputvar === "") {
    // is empty
}
```

and of course you should check for this condition first, if you want to handle numbers as input.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the given input value is a valid number or not

```
    function isNumber(n){ return /^-?[\d.]+(?:e-?\d+)?$/.test(n); }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Biegeleisen mentioned, it worked in this way:

```
var myinputvar = document.getElementById("myinput").value;
if (/^\s*$/.test(myinputvar)) {
   document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "Your input is blank";
} else {
  if (myinputvar > 10) {
     document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "Your input number is greater than 10";
  } else if (myinputvar < 10) {
    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "Your input number is less than 10";
  } else if (myinputvar = 10) {
    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "Your input number is 10";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASCII code to check for that

```
else if(myinputvar.carCodeAt(0) === 13) {
    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "Your input is blank";
}
```

13 is ASCII code of enter key
https://www.asciitable.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
> This method is also working, the logic is i should have use a nested
> if like this

 
function f1() {
            var myinputvar = document.getElementById("myinput").value;
            if (myinputvar == "") {
                document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "Your input is blank";
            } else {
                if (myinputvar > 10) {
                    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "Your input number is greater than 10";
                } else if (myinputvar < 10) {
                    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "Your input number is less than 10";
                } else if (myinputvar = 10) {
                    document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = "Your input number is 10";
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).